# Efficient way to repeatedly extract groups of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks in essence like the following:

```
Group   Date    Value   etc.
1       01/01   10
1       05/01   10
1       08/01   5
1       15/01   5
1       18/01   2
1       21/01   10
...
2       02/01   3
2       15/01   4
2       25/01   1
...
3       01/01   6
....
```

I would like extract each `Group` to a separate pandas dataframe containing all the rows in that group (eg to a dictionary with keys 1,2,3 etc). The obvious way to do this is using a slice (like `df[df.Group == 1]`) looping through the groups.

However, with a very quite large data set (700k rows, with 30k groups), the slice technique is quite slow because the entire 700k transactions must be accessed for each of the 30k groups.

Any suggestions for a faster method, where each of the 700k rows only has to be accessed once to perform the groupings? Thanks!

Comment: why do you need it in separate datasets?

Comment: I need to perform a series of operations on each group of rows, and to do this I just want the rows from that group. Otherwise I end up repeatedly performing slice operations on the whole set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want a separate df for each group, I'd just `groupby` on the 'group' and use the [`groups`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups) attribute to index back into the orig df, or use [`get_group`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group):

```
In [79]:
groups = df.groupby('Group')
groups.groups

Out[79]:
{1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2: [6, 7, 8], 3: [9]}

In [81]:    
groups.get_group(1)

Out[81]:
   Group   Date  Value
0      1  01/01     10
1      1  05/01     10
2      1  08/01      5
3      1  15/01      5
4      1  18/01      2
5      1  21/01     10

In [82]:    
df.loc[groups.groups[1]]

Out[82]:
   Group   Date  Value
0      1  01/01     10
1      1  05/01     10
2      1  08/01      5
3      1  15/01      5
4      1  18/01      2
5      1  21/01     10
```

Comment: very elegant, I did not know about `groups.get_group(...)`

Comment: Fantastic, `get_group` was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupby` on the `Group` column. This will get you all groups and you will be able to process each group with a function -

```
df.groupby('Group').<apply function here>
```

For example -

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
    Group   Date  Value
0       1  01/01     10
1       1  05/01     10
2       1  08/01      5
3       1  15/01      5
4       1  18/01      2
5       1  21/01     10
6       2  15/01      5
7       2  18/01      2
8       1  21/01     10
9       1  15/01      5
10      5  18/01      2
11      5  21/01     10

In [14]: df.groupby('Group').groups
Out[14]: {1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9], 2: [6, 7], 5: [10, 11]}

In [15]: grp = df.groupby('Group')
```

This gets you the Groups 1:

```
In [16]: grp.get_group(1)
Out[16]: 
   Group   Date  Value
0      1  01/01     10
1      1  05/01     10
2      1  08/01      5
3      1  15/01      5
4      1  18/01      2
5      1  21/01     10
8      1  21/01     10
9      1  15/01      5
```

The documentation here will help you further - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html

Comment: Thanks very much :-) I ticked the answer above because it came in first, but that was exactly what I was looking for.